# XDebug stops at shut-up operator (@)

Tags: php, xdebug

My xdebug stops at every shut-up operator, which is kind of nasty for me. (I know a lot of folks tend to say the shut-up operator should not be used but i strongly disagree in cases of accessing arrays and i think it makes a lot of code better readable. But that is not the topic here).

How can i prevent xdebug from doing so? `xdebug.scream=0` is explicitly set. I haven't found any other options that could help me with this.

php is `5.6.20` and xdebug is `2.2.5`

Comment: You mean it's breakpointing? That's likely a setting of your IDE. Also, not using the @ means that you're not hiding errors. Just do a simple !empty check first.

Comment: Yes it is breakpointing, and yes i know what `@` means and does. However i think its better readable code with `@`s than `empty()`. My IDE has very limited debugger settings (`Atom.io` with `php-debug`). The only configuration i can thin of is kind of error to stop at (but in my opinion @-marked code parts should not produce one), however disabling notices and warnings and strict standards did not help.

Comment: It might be readable, but it's also dangerous in some circumstances. No idea why Atom would be stopping there, though.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I know about dangers and there are a lot of other things to be handled with care as well. For me it is only usable in connection with an array accessor as a replacement for `empty($x['y']) ? null : $x['y'];`